# MongoDb - Find count using multiple and condition expressions

Tags: mongodb

The following query gives me count of all votes for a comment.

```
              $lookup: {
            from: "votesComments",
            as: "commentVotes",
            let: {
              commentI: "$_id"
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$commentId",
                      "$$commentI"
                    ],
                  },
                }
              },
              {
                $count: "votesTotal"
              },                  
            ]
          }
```

I am looking to add another AND condition to find how many of the votes have "1" in "up" field - This will give me count of all up votes. I tried the query below but does not work.

Is there a short query to get count of all comments with 1 in up field as "upTotal" and also get count of all 1 in down fields which will be total of downvotes?

```
        $match: {
                  $and:[
                  {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$commentId",
                      "$$commentI"
                    ],
                  },
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$up",
                      1
                    ],
                  },
                  },
                ]
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used and at the wrong place. This however is not the best way to find up and down votes as it needs 2 matches.

This is not the best answer I am sure.

```
                  $match: {
                  $expr: {
                      $and: [
                      {
                      $eq: [
                        "$commentId",
                        "$$commentI"
                      ],
                      },
                      {
                      $eq: [
                        "$up",
                        1
                      ],
                    }
                    ]
                  },
                }
```